# aiohttp router - not writing to logs

Tags: python, logging, aiohttp

I've got an `aiohttp` web app that uses routes as flask like decorators and `gunicorn`

I'm having some trouble getting the logs to work correctly though.

What am I missing here?

No error's are being thrown or logged and the app run smoothly, but nothing is being logged apart from the start-up logs:

```
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
[2018-10-16 09:41:18 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
```

My app/init.py file is as such:

```
import logging
import os
from logging import handlers
from aiohttp.web import Application
from app.routes import routes
from utils.logging import CloggerFormatter

def create_app(app_config):
    app = Application()
    logger = logging.getLogger('aiohttp.web')

    log_level = logging.DEBUG

    if os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL'):
        log_level = os.environ['LOG_LEVEL']

    app.router.add_routes(routes)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    logger.addHandler(CloggerFormatter)

    app['config'] = app_config

    return app
```

And then in my app/routes.py file I access the logger with `request.app.logger` from within the rout definition like:

```
from aiohttp.web import Response, RouteTableDef

routes = RouteTableDef()

@routes.post('/background-checks')
async def api_background_check(request):
    request_identifier = request.headers.get('X-Request-ID')

    if not request_identifier:
        request_identifier = uuid.uuid4()

    request.app.logger.info('Checking background for request: %s', request_identifier)
```

This is my utils/handlers/logging.py file:

```
from time import strftime, gmtime
from logging import Formatter

class CloggerFormatter(Formatter):
    """
    Logging module formatter in accordance with the yoti clogger manual
    guidelines.
    """
    converter = gmtime

    def __init__(self, datefmt=None):
        fmt = ('level:%(levelname)s'
               '\ttime:%(asctime)s'
               '\tmessage:%(message)s')

        Formatter.__init__(self, fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        """
        Return the creation time of the LogRecord using the RFC 3339
        format if datefmt is not specified.
        """
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = strftime(datefmt, ct)
        else:
            t = strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', ct)
            s = '%s.%03dZ' % (t, record.msecs)
        return s
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the root aiohttp logger: `logger = logging.getLogger('aiohttp')`.

Particularly *access logger* uses  `'aiohttp.access'` name but maybe you want to see other log messages like errors and warnings as well.